# Using UUID as document ID in Google Cloud Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, nosql, uuid

We are starting to use Google Cloud Firestore with Spring Cloud GCP.

We are thinking about adding a UUID as the document ID to every document -- mainly because we are used to it from using SQL databases.

However, there does not seem to be a native support for UUIDs in Firestore. Are there any advantages or disadvantages when using UUIDs as document IDs in Firestore?

Comment: What do you anticipate being a problem with this? It's hard to tell what sort of answer would be helpful.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There shouldn't be any problem to use a UUID as Firestore document ID.

The constraints on Firestore document ID are as follows, as detailed in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#collections_documents_and_fields):

> Constraints on document IDs
>
> - Must be valid UTF-8 characters
> - Must be no longer than 1,500 bytes
> - Cannot contain a forward slash (/)
> - Cannot solely consist of a single period (.) or double periods (..)
> - Cannot match the regular expression **.***

---

There is also a set of [Best Practices](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/best-practices#document_ids), as follows, but again, AFAK it shouldn't be a problem with UUID:

> - Avoid the document IDs . and ...
> - Avoid using / forward slashes in document IDs.
> - Do not use monotonically increasing document IDs such as:
>
>   - Customer1, Customer2, Customer3, ...
>   - Product 1, Product 2, Product 3, ...
>
>     Such sequential IDs can lead to hotspots that impact latency.

Comment: "Cannot match the regular expression .*" Isn't this any possible text?

Comment: It actually can't match the regex `__.*__`